# Fedora 23 realtek ehternet works on livecd, but doesn't on a fresh install

Tags: linux, fedora, ethernet, livecd

`lspci | grep -i ethernet` gives the same for livecd and fresh install:

```
02:00.1 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 12)`
```

`lsmod | grep -i r816.*` also gives that module `r8169` is loaded on both systems

Configuration through network manager is also the same.
But for some reason ethernet works fine on livecd, and doesn't work on the installed system

Answer (score 0):

So, I fixed it myself. Interface seemed up from network settings, but i tried to `ip link set enp2s0f1 up` and it worked for some reason